# Domain Search does not look into database fields

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I am pretty used to Domino Full-Text Search syntax, and searching for values in particular fields is as simple as `[FieldName]="some value"`. Easy peasy.

Problem arises using Domino Domain Search. It works well for free searches, but seems unable to understand `[FieldName]=` or `FIELD fieldname CONTAINS` syntax. Every single attemp I made have returned a "No documents found" message.

Has anyone ever made it work?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you Run "Domain Indexer" task on your server...
You can see Domain Index Status in "catalog.nsf" on server, see outline.
If your open "Catalog" in Designer, you can find "Search Form" and "DBSearch" lotusscript library. 
You should see them, there described working with the fields and categories database.
FT-syntax work fine and equally.

Comment: @PauOlesh, so far I have been unable to make a Domain Search that restrict its searching to specified fields. Things like `[fieldname]="fieldvalue"` always return a No Documents Found message.

Comment: @AndreKrepsky, sorry... send-by-enter =) I found this link [refine_query](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTWP_8.5.3/com.ibm.notes85.client.doc/sch_refine_query_r.html) This **syntax** not work in Domain, only view and web...(my mistake) I hope that link can help you in future.